# Why are the map markers icons not changing?

Tags: flutter

This is my code

```
  void addCustomIcon(){
    BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(
      const ImageConfiguration(), "assets/camera_icon.png")
    .then(
      (icon){
        setState(() {
          markerIcon = icon;
        });
      }
    );
  }

void initState() {
  addCustomIcon();
  intilize();
  super.initState();
}
intilize(){
  Marker m1 = Marker(
    markerId: MarkerId('m1'),
    position: LatLng(1.33397173881531,  103.77531433105469),
    infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: 'Marker 1'),
    icon: markerIcon,
    );}
```

This is the code for google maps:

```
GoogleMap(
              initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(target: LatLng(1, 100), zoom: 16),
              markers: markers.map((e) => e).toSet(),
              trafficEnabled: true,
              myLocationEnabled: true,
              mapType: MapType.normal,)
```

I'm trying to get the marker icon to change to a camera_icon in my assets file but it still shows me the red default marker. What should I do to change the marker icons to the camera_icon?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you assigned the marker to markerIcon asynchronously, this executed in the `addCustomIcon()` and there is another function name `initialize()` to assign the icon result of `addCustomIcon()` to `Set<Marker>`, I guess the problem is because this `addCustomIcon()` haven't done yet, and the `initialize()` gets called early it does not wait for the `addCustomIcon()` to do the assignment process.

Then try this:

```
List<Marker> markers = [];

void addCustomIcon() async {
  BitmapDescriptor icon = await BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(
    const ImageConfiguration(),
    'assets/camera_icon.png',
  );

  setState(() {
    markers = [
      Marker(
        markerId: MarkerId('m1'),
        position: LatLng(1.33397173881531,  103.77531433105469),
        infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: 'Marker 1'),
        icon: icon,
      ),
    ];
  });
}

@override
void initState() {
  addCustomIcon();
  super.initState();
}

// ...

GoogleMap(
  initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(target: LatLng(1, 100), zoom: 16),
  markers: markers.toSet(),
  trafficEnabled: true,
  myLocationEnabled: true,
  mapType: MapType.normal,
),
```

I make a few changes here, so add the content of the `initialize()` function inside the `addCustomIcon()`.

Comment: I got an error on :
'throw PlatformException(code: errorCode, message: errorMessage as String?, details: errorDetails, stacktrace: errorStacktrace);' in messagecodecs.dart What does that mean?